# pygame looping through a movement with a Class instance

Tags: python, pygame

I can't figure out how to loop through the jump function without having it in the first 'while True' block. None of the proposed alternatives have worked so far. Currently the only way I get it to work is having to press spacebar for each step of the jump.

```
import pygame
from pygame import Color

HEIGHT = 500
WIDTH = 400
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((HEIGHT, WIDTH))


class Bird:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 10
        self.y = 300
        self.vy = 5
        self.jumpCount = 10
        self.isJump = False

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, Color("yellow"), (self.x, self.y, 10, 10))
        pygame.display.flip()

    def jump(self):

        if self.isJump:
            # using 'while' doesn't work either
            if self.jumpCount >= -10:
                # this doesn't work -> pygame.time.delay(100)
                print(self.jumpCount)
                self.y += (self.jumpCount * abs(self.jumpCount)) * -0.5
                self.jumpCount -= 1
            else:
                self.jumpCount = 10
                self.isJump = False

        return self.isJump

    def move(self):
        return

def run():
    bird = Bird()
    while True:

        pygame.time.delay(100)
        # only works if I put 'bird.isJump = True, bird.jump()' here, and then it loops continuously
        surface.fill(Color("blue"))
        bird.draw()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == 32:
                    bird.isJump = True
                    bird.jump()
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
        pygame.display.flip()


run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call the `move` method every time you run the game loop, along with `draw`, then call the `jump` method only once, when space is clicked.

The result will be (with a few other minor changes, such as calling `pygame.init`, quitting with `quit` instead of `pygame.quit` and removing redundant class members):

```
import pygame
from pygame import Color


class Bird:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 10
        self.y = 300
        self.jumpCount = 10
        self.isJump = False

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, Color("yellow"), (self.x, self.y, 10, 10))
        pygame.display.flip()

    def jump(self):
        self.jumpCount = 10
        self.isJump = True

    def move(self):
        if self.isJump:
            if self.jumpCount >= -10:
                self.y += (self.jumpCount * abs(self.jumpCount)) * -0.5
                self.jumpCount -= 1
            else:
                self.isJump = False


def run():
    bird = Bird()
    while True:

        pygame.time.delay(100)
        surface.fill(Color("blue"))
        bird.move()
        bird.draw()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == 32:
                    bird.jump()
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit()
        pygame.display.flip()


pygame.init()
HEIGHT = 500
WIDTH = 400
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((HEIGHT, WIDTH))
run()
```

Comment: thank you very much, although I'm curious why it doesn't work if I use while statement or loop it within run